# Mayweather Credit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Hi I'm having trouble with a classwork problem to validate a credit card number through an algorithm, I thought I had the code right but I can't pinpoint why it only displays invalid. Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Option Strict On


Public Class frmMain

 Private Sub Multiply(ByRef strCreditCard As String)


    Dim dblSecondDigit, dblSecondDigitSub As Double
    Dim dblFourthDigit, dblFourthDigitSub As Double
    Dim dblCheckDigit As Double
    Dim strSecondDigit, strFourthDigit, strCheckDigit As String

    ' multiplies the second and fourth digits by 2

    Double.TryParse(strCreditCard.Substring(1, 1), dblSecondDigit)
    Double.TryParse(strCreditCard.Substring(3, 1), dblFourthDigit)

    dblSecondDigit = dblSecondDigit * 2
    dblFourthDigit = dblFourthDigit * 2

    If dblSecondDigit > 9 Then

        strSecondDigit = System.Convert.ToString(dblSecondDigit)
        Double.TryParse(strSecondDigit.Substring(0, 1), dblSecondDigit)
        Double.TryParse(strSecondDigit.Substring(1, 1), dblSecondDigitSub)

        dblSecondDigit = dblSecondDigit + dblSecondDigitSub


        If dblFourthDigit > 9 Then


            strFourthDigit = System.Convert.ToString(dblFourthDigit)
            Double.TryParse(strFourthDigit.Substring(0, 1), dblFourthDigit)
            Double.TryParse(strFourthDigit.Substring(1, 1), dblFourthDigitSub)

            dblFourthDigit = dblFourthDigit + dblFourthDigitSub

        End If
    End If

    ' Add and divide the credit card digits
    Dim dblFirstDigit, dblThirdDigit As Double
    Dim dblSum As Double

    Double.TryParse(strCreditCard.Substring(0, 1), dblFirstDigit)
    Double.TryParse(strCreditCard.Substring(2, 1), dblThirdDigit)

    dblSum = dblFirstDigit + dblSecondDigit + dblThirdDigit + dblFourthDigit

    If dblSum Mod 10 > 0 Then

        dblSum = 10 - dblSum

        strCheckDigit = System.Convert.ToString(dblSum)
        strCreditCard.Insert(3, strCheckDigit)
    Else
        strCheckDigit = System.Convert.ToString(dblSum)
        strCreditCard.Insert(3, strCheckDigit)
    End If


    Double.TryParse(strCreditCard.Substring(4, 1), dblCheckDigit)

    If dblCheckDigit = 1 Then

        lblValidation.Text = "Valid"
    Else
        lblValidation.Text = "Invalid"

    End If




End Sub


Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnVerify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVerify.Click

    Dim strCreditCard As String

    ' store user input into a string variable 
    strCreditCard = txtCreditCard.ToString

    Call Multiply(strCreditCard)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Pass txtCreditCart.Text to your method, not the class name

Comment: Thanks you're completely right that was driving me nuts because I couldn't find anything wrong with the sub.